# What is the minimal usage for including data in a python 3 package build using distutils setup()?

Tags: python, package, setuptools, distutils

I am trying to build my first package in `python 3.6.3`. I've read through the docs and searched the questions, but can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

My package directory structure is as follows:

```
| - mypkg/
|   | - setup.py 
|   | - someModule/
|   |   | - __init__.py
|   |   | - a.py
|   |   | - b.py
|   |   | - data /
|   |   |   |- somedata.xml
```

My setup script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(...
      packages=['someModule'],
      data_files = [('someModule', ['someModule/data/somedata.xml'])]
      )
```

However when I run `python setup.py build` my data is not being added to the `build/lib/mypkg` directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do read the Python Packaging Guide, it has a [tutorial on this very subject](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/).

Comment: You don't have a `mypkg` package in your directory. Only a `someModule` package.

Comment: `data_files` is for data that lives **outside** of the installed package. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: Yes, have read, but as mentioned in the question, have not understood. Hence the question... Thanks have changed `mypkg` to `someModule`

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `setuptools.find_packages()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. In the end using the `package_data` argument instead of the `data_files` argument did it, i.e. I changed `setup.py` to:

```
setup(...
      packages = ['someModule'],
      package_data = {'someModule': ['data/somedata.xml']},
      )
```

Thanks to @Martijn Pieters for the tip that `data_files` is for data that lives outside the package.